Lightweight backend solution for React webapp
I am starting a new project, it is a simple react webapp that simply has an about page for a company and a catalogue page for available items (no payment system system/method integration, as the webapp will simply generate a quote for business owners to follow up with). I am looking for a backend solution that will expose endpoints for simple stuff:

Log in (userID and hashed password)
Product information (name, description and images per product)
Active Quotations (ProductIDs, quantity and active status - T/F)

Given the limited scope of the backend I am looking for something lightweight & high velocity (high velocity in development time)
Possible options are Express.js & mongodb or Django & mongodb. However I feel like there is something more agile out there for this simple use case
